# Function that returns the content of multiple .txt files python

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to write a function that traverses a given path and opens/reads all the .txt files therein and returns these as a string or returns a value that I can use to apply text normalization.

Currently my code only returns the first .txt file it finds, except when I use a print(f.read()) statement, then it prints all the files it read.

I would like it to return all the files

```
def readtxt(path):
import os
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            filelist = filepath.split()
            for file in filelist:
                with open(os.path.join(path, filepath), 'r') as f: 
                    lines = (f.read())
                    return lines
readtxt('/Users/path/')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a `return` statement, the function ends. That's why it only gives you 1 file - it stops when it finds one. You could add them all into a `list` & return that afterwards instead.

```py
found = []
```

And then, inside of your loops, you simply do:

```py
with open(os.path.join(path, filepath), 'r') as f: 
    lines = (f.read())
    found.append(lines) # Append to list instead of returning
```

so that you can return *everything* you found using:

```py
return found
```

Comment: Thank you very very much! Very clear and informative answer wich worked!

Comment: If it worked then you should mark it as correct.